How to create an Xcode UI Test Target in CMake
Xcode has two template types of testing: Unit Test Targets and UI Test Targets, which run the host application differently. Looking online, I don't see any clear distinction of how these host targets are run differently, just that the unit tests will import a testable bundle to invoke specific classes, while the UI test bundle will create an instance of XCUIApplication at runtime.
Picture from Xcode target creation flow:

If I could find somewhere describing the differences between these targets more technically, then I could start looking at how to change my cmake script to setup each target to match.
CMake has xctest_add_bundle as part of FindXCTest, which seems to create an Xcode Unit Test Target.
There doesn't appear to be a specific way to create a UI Test Target directly with CMake, but how can I alter a xctest_add_bundle test bundle in my CMake script such that I can create a UI Test Target that matches Xcode "UI Testing Bundle"?

There are two key things here.
First:
It's not very well documented, but CMake has a target property called XCODE_PRODUCT_TYPE (see here), but it doesn't say any of the typical values. If you manually open up a project file project.pbxproj in another IDE (I couldn't find this exposed anywhere in the Xcode GUI), you can find that a UITests target will have productType = com.apple.product-type.bundle.ui-testing. Setting this is the key part for making the target seen by Xcode as a UI Tests bundle instead of a unit tests bundle.
Second: Another SO post about unit testing pointed me to a retired Apple document which discusses "Application unit tests" instead of "UI tests". So old Xcode refers to both of these types as "unit tests".
CMake's xctest_add_bundle takes the test target name and testee target name. This automatically adds the "Test Host" and "Bundle Loader" build settings mentioned in those apple docs. So xctest_add_bundle seems to be actually creating some sort of hybrid of a "UI Testing Bundle" and a unit test bundle.
Pulling that all together, in order to make a proper "UI Testing Bundle" as Xcode would make it, you can do:
# MyApp is your defined app
find_package(XCTest REQUIRED)
xctest_add_bundle(UITests MyApp
    Tests/Tests.swift
)
set_target_properties(UITests PROPERTIES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_TEST_HOST ""
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_BUNDLE_LOADER ""
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_TEST_TARGET_NAME MyApp
    XCODE_PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.bundle.ui-testing
)

This still gives the UI test target icon in the Xcode targets list and now properly allows the XCUIApplication to run.

Big applause for saving my day! It's kind of rare for CMake world to find short and clear explanation with working example. Thanks for sharing!
